# Printing unique list of indices in multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I am just starting out with pandas and have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'num_legs': [4, 4, 2, 2, 2],
'num_wings': [0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
'class': ['mammal', 'mammal','bird-mammal', 'mammal', 'bird'],
'animal': ['cat', 'dog','cat', 'bat', 'penguin'],
'locomotion': ['walks', 'walks','hops', 'flies', 'walks']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.set_index(['class', 'animal', 'locomotion'])
```

I want to print everything that the animal cat does; here, that will be 'walks' and 'hops'.

I can filter to just the cat cross-section using

```
df2=df.xs('cat', level=1)
```

But from here, how do I access the level 'locomotion'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `get_level_values`

```
df.xs('cat', level=1).index.get_level_values(1)
Out[181]: Index(['walks', 'hops'], dtype='object', name='locomotion')
```